# Using the specified output convention by android, how do I go about reading output files

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator, ddms, fileoutputstream

I'm using the following link in Android development:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal

with the following important code in my project:

```
String FILENAME = "hello_file";
String string = "hello world!";

FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
fos.write(string.getBytes());
fos.close();
```

I couldn't seem to find the file "hello_file" anywhere on my computer, but when I ran the emulator in Eclipse, and then used DDMS (whatever that is) I was able to locate the file within the emulator...? This makes intuitive sense as the file would be outputted into the folders of a fully built app, not some Eclipse project folder- my question, really, is this- how do I go about opening and editing the file up- shouldn't there be a folder that contains the emulator's files in it? Through DDMS, I can see that "hello_file" exists, but I can't do anything with it...

Answer (score 0):

No. The file you write to internal storage is private as stated in the document.

> You can save files directly on the device's internal storage. By
>   default, files saved to the internal storage are private to your
>   application and other applications cannot access them (nor can the
>   user). When the user uninstalls your application, these files are
>   removed.

The reason you can find the file in emulator because it is 'rooted' and can have access to all files in the file system. You cannot find this file on a real unrooted device.

Comment: So is there any way I can make them public?

Comment: No, because its not intened to be. You can root your phone if you really want. You can also use code to 'load it' and save to external storage.